# SAML2 Okta - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: saml-2.0, okta, onelogin

I am writing the backend flow of SAML2 integration, using Okta as an IDP (Identity Provider) and myself as a SP (Service Provider). 
I am using python 3.5 and flask, and writing the flow with Onelogin's library - python3-saml using this manual https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml.
When executing the command `auth.login`, which redirects me to Okta, I get the following error:

`Failed to load https://dev-766941.oktapreview.com/app/<domain_name>dev766941_<domain_name>_1/exkfytpisliPsvo8w0h7/sso/saml?RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.<domain_name>.com%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Flogin%2Fsaml%2F&SAMLRequest=fVNdj9owEHy%2FXxHlHRxzaQgWIFHoBxKFCGgf%2BoJ8zuawLrFTrwPcv68duMJJPaJIUdazs7Oz6yHyqqzZpLF7tYY%2FDaB9CIJTVSpk7dEobIximqNEpngFyKxgm8mPBet1I1YbbbXQZfgu6X4ORwRjpVY%2BaT4bhavll8Xq23y5ix6fkjjOCxrlRT8q0gF9TIrCBdKU9wc0Sfo07cVx4hN%2FgUHHMQodZUuE2MBcoeXKumBE0w6N3LulEYsjRj%2F99qiZ608qbtvMvbU1MkJyOHT6STKIaVe%2FWF4bOEg4doWuCK9rwk0l0WHOkF37u6METi%2FFq60lljLDg06P0b5PEDXxDvha2cWbz1LlUj3fN%2BXpDEL2fbvNOtlqs%2FUUkzerplphU4HZgDlIAT%2FXi6t863rq9bqtrla0Uy0JdxMlpX6WinCBJBw7uiAYenGs9cqMPyaowPKcW06G5DbhSlGzpWthPst0KcVrG%2FfPV20qbj%2FulHZpG5F5p2ihrFFYg5CFhDz8RzMpS32cGuAWRqE1DYQBeVf8sqmQt3vrzLFwssFUVzU3Ev1s4cSFvTR9bfwWPi3dIq6hGN%2FdVcGEx7lw5j5HbXI%2FVhCu9tZwJ14bezHpv%2BRn1eSO7PHD2%2FHtJRz%2FBQ%3D%3D: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://test.<domain_name>.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I added `https://test.domain_name.com` to the "Trusted Origins" in my okta settings page using this manual https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/enabling_cors and it didn't help ( I tried adding to CORS and to Redirect and also each one separately).
I also tried to add `https://developer.okta.com` to the "Trusted Origins" and it also didn't help.

One last thing I tried was adding the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the request, but it didn't add the header to the Okta request but to the request I have in my code (meaning, it added the header to the request that calls a function, auth.login, that internally calls to Okta instead to the request to Okta).

I would be very happy for any suggestions.

Comment: Any update on this, I too facing same now. Please let me know if it is fixed.